# OneToOne Bidirectional Hibernate - How do I replace the child and persist?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

How can I "replace" the child of a bidirectional oneToOne relationship successfully?

I have a parent-child oneToOne bidirectional relationship with shared primary key setup successfully.

- I can create/persist a detached/new parent and child successfully. The child key is updated correctly.
- I can retrieve the parent and access the child through the relationship.
- I can modify attributes of the parent, the child or both and successfully update.
- I can remove the child by setting parent.setChild(null) and update deletes the child.

However, I cannot successfully replace the child with a detached child.

```
Class Parent {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CLAIMNUMBER_GENERATOR")
   @Column(name = "CLAIM_NUMBER")
   private long claimNumber;

   @OneToOne(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, 
             cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, orphanRemoval = true)
   private Child child;
}
```

```
Class Child {
   @Id
   @Column(name = "CLAIM_NUMBER")
   private long claimNumber;

   @OneToOne
   @MapsId
   @JoinColumn(name = "CLAIM_NUMBER")
   private Parent parent;
}
```

My Test - pseudo code

```
 1. Start transaction
 2. Create and persist new parent and child
 3. em.flush
 4. parent = session.get(Parent.class, parent.getClaimNumber())
 5. newChild = Build new/detached child with ID (ie. claimNumber) equal zero
 6. parent.setChild(newChild)
 7. newChild.setParent(parent)
 8. session.merge(parent) <--- dies here
 9. em.flush
```

At the point it dies, I get an exception:

```
javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [Child#xxxxx]
```

In addition, I have tried with unsuccessful results:

1. Setting the ID to zero and parent to null in the original child before adding the new child.
2. Setting the child attribute to null in the parent before adding the new child.**
3. Tried implementing hashcode() and equals() on the child to help hibernate identify it as a different object.

**If I flush() after I set the child attribute to null in the parent. It works but I don't think that is a very good (transparent/intuitive) solution for using it throughout the code. It just feels unnecessary when using an ORM layer.

Comment: Apparently, the identifier for the entity is the same as before, so why can't you just apply the stat onto the existing child?

Comment: Basically, the newChild is built from another source and provided. So, I could write a mergeChild() myself. But, hey, we have a super smart ORM layer here. Why not use it? A "natural" OOO usage IMHO is to just replace the child and continue. Thus, my final comment on the post. This may be what I end up doing.

Comment: It should also be possible to use `em.clear()` after the `session.get()` call. This way, there will be no managed entities anymore and the merge should just work. "Replacing" an object that other objects refer to is not that easy unfortunately because Hibernate has to keep track of the object identity.

Comment: So in the end did you manage to find a solution for this?